# Firebase/Flutter - cannot write data to database

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing my Flutter App which requires users to upload certain images to Firebase.
Everything is working flawlessly for authentication of users and storing images to Firebase storage.
In the part when user is required to upload a picture with a description from his phone all I get is picture in my storage part of Firebase **but no description and other metadata in my database**.

I checked database rules and they are public and working fine.

This is the current code for image upload part that is working fine:

```
 void uploadStatusImage() async {
if (validateAndSave()) {
  final Reference postImageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Post Images");
  var timeKey = new DateTime.now();

  final Task uploadTask =
      postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString() + ".jpg").putFile(sampleImage);

  var ImageUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();

  url = ImageUrl.toString();

  print("Image URL = " + url);

  goToHomePage();
  saveToDatabase(url);
}
```

and this is the database part which is not working:

```
void saveToDatabase(url) {
var dbTimeKey = new DateTime.now();
var formatDate = new DateFormat('MMM d, yyyy');
var formatTime = new DateFormat('EEEE, hh:mm aa');

String date = formatDate.format(dbTimeKey);
String time = formatTime.format(dbTimeKey);

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

var data = {
  "image": url,
  "description": _myValue,
  "date": date,
  "time": time,
};
ref.child("Posts").push().set(data);
```

VS code is not giving me any errors and app is working fine in my android emulator.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem in flutter/web (data not written in the db, but no dart exceptions), and the problem was due to an incorrect url in the configuration file to initialize the FirebaseApp. In Android things could be different, cmq I suggest you to check the configuration json file (in particular that databaseUrl corresponds with what you see in the firebase console).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save to database before going to home page?

```
  void uploadStatusImage() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      final Reference postImageRef =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Post Images");
      var timeKey = new DateTime.now();

      final Task uploadTask =
          postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString() + ".jpg").putFile(sampleImage);

      var ImageUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();

      url = ImageUrl.toString();

      print("Image URL = " + url);

      saveToDatabase(url); // Switch positions
      goToHomePage(); // <-----
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but same thing :/ uploading images to storage works , but no data in my database.

Comment: Did you try await for when calling set ? 

Comment: await ref.child("Posts").child(newKey).set(data);   -  tried like that,still not working.. thanks for your help though!

Comment: Maybe the new edit does it? Now I'm integrated

Comment: i already suspected that was a mistake before writing all of this and tried it but result is the same... :/